# CSS Hack for Mobiles

Tags: css, mobile

I have a site that uses a custom font from google fonts. On my website it is aligned normally, but on my android, the source is out of alignment. Researched by various mobile tricks, and I wonder if any of them actually work, because, as tested one by one, and it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width 480px)

::made-up-pseudo-element, .selector {}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){}
```

**Solution**

Before use this hacks, add this line in your `<head>` HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Major Browsers render line-height differently if not specified. Put `line-height: 15px;` in the body or more/less.